# Xdebug trace function how to exclude vendor dir

Tags: php, xdebug, trace, xdebug-profiler

I am using Xdebug to analyze my Laravel code. I use the trace and coverage function.

For coverage, I can config whitelist and exclude to configure what directory and file I want to analyze.

But for trace, I don't know how to configure the exclude directory. Like `vendor`, I think they are no change, so I want to exclude them. I just want to focus on my code.

Do you know how I can configure trace exclude or blacklist?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="true" colors="true" convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true" convertWarningsToExceptions="true" stopOnFailure="false">
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="false" addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="false">
            <directory suffix=".php">./../</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".php">./../vendor</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
        <blacklist>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For removing things from traces, you can use Xdebug's [xdebug_set_filter()](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_set_filter) function.
There is an example in the manual, which reads as follows:

> To exclude all files in the vendor sub-directory in traces:
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <?php
> xdebug_set_filter(
>     XDEBUG_FILTER_TRACING, XDEBUG_PATH_BLACKLIST, 
>     [ __DIR__ . "/vendor/" ]
> );
> ?>
> ```

You need Xdebug 2.6 or later for this to work. You can either put this in your `index.php` script, or otherwise in an [auto_prepend](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) script. The only important note is that this line needs to be run before the include/calls within the `/vendor/` folder are executed.

FWIW, In Xdebug 3, `XDEBUG_PATH_BLACKLIST` will be [renamed](https://3.xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#Changed-Constants) to `XDEBUG_PATH_EXCLUDE`.